# Linq query for list of strings assign to ViewModel in C#.net?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my model

```
class BaseModel
{
  public string Status{get;set;}
  public List<Error>  Errors{get;set;}
}

class Error
{
 public  string Code {get;set;}
 public  string Message {get;set;}
}
```

I have list of error messages like .

```
var errors = validator.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToList();
```

I write the for loop code as following

```
BaseModel response=new BaseModel();
 for (int i = 0; i < errors.Count; i++)
 {
     response.Errors[i].Message = errors[i];                        
 }
```

But i want to write same use linq query in c#.net. I tries the following code but its error.

```
 response.Errors = new List<Error> { new Error { Message = errors, Code = "500" } };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select()` to create `Error` class object like

```
BaseModel response=new BaseModel();
response.Errors = validator.Errors
                  .Select(e => new Error 
                  {
                       Message = e.ErrorMessage, 
                       Code = "500"
                  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `Error` instance for each validator error.

```
response.Errors = validator.Errors
                  .Select(e => new Error 
                  { 
                       Message = e.ErrorMessage, 
                       Code = "500"  // use actual value.
                  }).ToList();
```